# Pay with paypal and recurring using billing agreement API

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I just want to understand that how can I redirect user to PayPal account ==> login ==> agreed to payment teand based on selection I can call my Billing Agreement Rest API.

Do I need to setUp My Own UI to process payment ?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing here is that you cannot sign a billing agreement without a billing plan

So the first thing you need to consider is how you could create a plan.
Its very simple just trigger this api: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/
Now you have your plan Id
now you can subscribe a user with this plan id
by triggering this API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_create